# How to check javafx label for texT?

Tags: javafx

Im trying to create a program  that allows a person to write a reminder into a textfield which is then added to a label. Im trying to code my submit button by asking if the label has text, if it doesnt it prints on that label, if it does it moves to the next label to check for text so that im not overwriting the same label over and over again. How can I check to see if a Label already has text?

This is my code so far:

```
     TextField text;
       @Override public void start(Stage stage){
      text = new TextField();
      text.setPromptText("Enter task here:");
      text.setPrefColumnCount(20);
      Label label1 = new Label();
      Label label2 = new Label();
      Label label3 = new Label();

      Button button = new Button("Click");
      button.setOnAction(e -> {
        if (label1.getText() = something there) {
            nothing
        } else {
             label1.setText(text.getText());
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(!label1.getText().isEmpty())
{
    //TODO
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Cant understand why I didnt see that on Oracle docs.

Comment: If this solved your problem, don't forget to accept the answer to close the question. :-)